# Generating random simulations of events

Tags: normal-distribution, matlab, random-variable, simulation

Whole-edited to make it more simple.

Let's assume we have a concrete event: `A baseball player's batting average is 0.32.`

I want to find a random number X, that this player will hit the ball in 1000 tries. A simple way of doing this would be to generate a number Y between 0-1, 1000 times, and check if each time he hits the ball or not (i.e. whether Y is < or > than 0.32)

I am trying to do this more efficiently (i.e. without running 1000 simulations). I just want to find the number of total balls he hits.

I did a bunch of research and it seems we have a [Binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), for which we have to generate an [Inverse Cumulative Distribution Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function) (which will transform our random number Y between 0-1 to a number X which will be how many times the player actually hit the ball).

I took a look at a bunch of papers and found a few methods. I think this guy lays it out well [Efficient evaluation](http://www.lancaster.ac.uk/postgrad/moorhead/Work/SummerProject13.pdf).

**Question:** I still would love for someone to explain me how he gets his `Normal Asymptotic Approximation`, or maybe point me to a video/paper that better explains it, or otherwise explain me how his MatLab code in the appendix works.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "we want to do this in constant time"?

Comment: Meaning, have an algorithm that can do this computationally, without looping over the number of bat hits (100). I know that we can generate 100 numbers, one at a time and see how many hits we have. But i would want to do this at once, mathematically, hopefully

Comment: Are you perhaps asking how to calculate the inverse cumulative distribution function (or quantile function) of a Binomial distribution? Or maybe drawing random values from a Binomial distribution?

Comment: I think either would be good (i.e. once you have one, the other one should be trivial), but since I am not too familiar with [quantile function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function), I tried to explain the problem by example

Comment: If all you want to do is avoid a loop, try: rbinom(1,100,.32)

Comment: Are you asking for code (for what language)? Are you asking how in principle such a thing is possible?

Comment: I am asking for 1. if this is possible computationally, without looping over the number of events, 2. what algorithm / idea, i need to look into.

Comment: When you say "we should be able to find the inverse" can you be precise about the thing you want to compute there?

Answer (score 2):

> A baseball player's batting average is 0.32
>
> We want to randomly simulate 100 times at bat and find out how many times our player actually hits the ball in this simulation. We want to do this in constant time, meaning do one calculation and not one after the other.

If the at-bats are independent trials and the probability at each bat is constant at 0.32, then the number of hits in 100 trials is binomial(100,0.32)

Many packages provide both random generation from a binomial and the cdf and inverse cdf. For example, R has all of these.

(If you have the incomplete beta function, you can also use the relationship between the beta and the binomial to get tail areas.)

If you need to simulate binomial random variates yourself, you can compute the table for the pmf, and use something like a table method (which is very fast) or squaring the histogram; alternatively you could use a suitable multiple of a Gaussian majorizing function, rounded to integer with accept-reject, which would be quite reasonable - e.g. using a normal with a mean of 32 and a variance of 24, the scale factor needed is only 1.057004.